# Is this a faulty PSU Issue?

Tags: power-supply

I have a PC that has been working for 2 years then yesterday it stopped working and shut down.

Now when I turn it on, the PSU comes on for a few seconds and then stops. There are no beeps from the BIOS.

Is it likely to be a PSU issue?

Comment: do you get display when it comes on? could you also check the processor fan is secured on snug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It it could be a PSU issue or a motherboard issue. Just to be safe, check the insides of your PC and see if there are any short-circuits visible (for example bare cables touching case or solder points touching case).

Unfortunately, the only way to be sure is to check it out with PSU which is known to work correctly.

Comment: +1 - changing out the PSU is the only way to tell for sure!

Comment: i thought the only way to be sure was a 'nuke from orbit'?

Comment: @Sirex Well, no. This way contaminated fragments can still remain. Toss it into black hole is much safer solution to all problems. :)

Comment: New PSU fitted and it's okay now. Thanks :-)